# Reverse indices of a sorted list

Tags: python, sorting

I want to return the '***reverse***' indices of a sorted list. What I mean by that is: I have an unsorted list `U` and I sort it via `S=sorted(U)`. Now, I can get the sort indices such that `U(idx)=S` - but I want `S(Ridx) = U`.

Here a little example:

```
U=[5,2,3,1,4]

S=sorted(U)

idx = [U.index(S[i]) for i in range(len(U))]
>>> idx
[3, 1, 2, 4, 0]

Ridx = [S.index(U[i]) for i in range(len(U))]
>>> Ridx
[4, 1, 2, 0, 3]

>>>[U[idx[i]] for i in range(len(U))] == S
True

>>>[S[Ridx[i]] for i in range(len(U))] == U
True
```

What I need is an efficient way to get Ridx.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

All right! I did a little speed test for both of the solutions (@Jon Clements and @Whatang) which answered the question.

The script:

```
import datetime as DT
import random

U=[int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(pow(10,8))]

S=sorted(U)

idx = sorted(xrange(len(U)), key=U.__getitem__)

T0 = DT.datetime.now()
ridx = sorted(xrange(len(U)), key=idx.__getitem__)
print [S[ridx[i]] for i in range(len(U))]==U
elapsed = DT.datetime.now()-T0
print str(elapsed)

print '==============='
T0 = DT.datetime.now()
ridx = [ y for (x,y) in sorted(zip(idx, range(len(idx)))) ]
print [S[ridx[i]] for i in range(len(U))]==U
elapsed = DT.datetime.now()-T0
print str(elapsed)
```

And the results:

```
True
0:02:45.278000
===============
True
0:06:48.889000
```

Thank you all for the quick and meaningful help!

Comment: Are you looking for the index of the `i`th element of `U` in `S`, or the index of the `i`th element of `S` in `U`?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Can you give us some short sample data, the intended output, and the stripped-down code you've written, instead of making us guess?

Comment: the `i`th element of `S` in `U`

Comment: @ZappaZ:  That really does not clarify it.  Could you post a short example?

Comment: Implementing your own binary search is redundant.  Such capability exists in the `bisect` module.

Comment: Sure: `U=[5,2,3,1,4]` which via `S=sorted(U)` will lead to `S=[1,2,3,4,5]`. The usual indices which are returned by something like: `[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(myList), key=lambda x:x[1])]` would be `idx=[4,1,2,0,3]`. Now I want `Ridx` such that `S[Ridx]==U`, where `Ridx=[3,1,2,4,0]`

Comment: For each item in the sorted list you want the index of that item in the original list, correct?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: correct!

Comment: Do you have control over `U`? If so you could build it such that the indices are included with the items. Then all you'd need is a regular sort and an iterator that selects the indices from the sorted list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient I can think of (short of possibly looking to `numpy`) that gets rid of the `.index` and can be used for both `idx` and `ridx`:

```
U=[5,2,3,1,4]
idx = sorted(xrange(len(U)), key=U.__getitem__)
ridx = sorted(xrange(len(U)), key=idx.__getitem__)
# [3, 1, 2, 4, 0] [4, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Comment: From what I tell it works nicely! Will post the performance of this method once I'll get in the office. Thanks!

Comment: @ZappaZ it will certainly be faster than indexing, but will be curious as to how it gets on... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the data structure you asked for, but I think this gets the info you want:

```
>>> sorted(x[::-1] for x in enumerate(['z', 'a', 'c', 'x', 'm']))
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('m', 4), ('x', 3), ('z', 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

With numpy you can do

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> U = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]

>>> np.array(U).argsort().argsort()
array([4, 1, 2, 0, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the list `idx`, you can do

```
ridx = [ y for (x,y) in sorted(zip(idx, range(len(idx)))) ]
```

Then for all `i` from 0 to `len(U)`

```
S[ridx[i]] == U[i]
```

You can avoid the sort if you use a dictionary:

```
ridx_dict = dict(zip(idx, range(len(idx))))
```

which can then be converted to a list:

```
ridx = [ ridx_dict[k] for k in range(len(idx)) ]
```

Thinking about permutations is the key to this problem. One way of writing down a permutation is to write all the indexes in order on one line, then on the line below write the new index of the element with that index. e.g., for your example

```
0 1 2 3 4
3 1 2 4 0
```

This second line is your `idx` list. You read down the columns, so the element which starts at index 0 moves to index 3, the element which starts at index 1 stays at index 1, and so on.

The [inverse permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Product_and_inverse) is the `ridx` you're looking for. To find this, sort the lower line of the your permutation keeping columns together, then write down the new top line. So the example becomes:

```
4 1 2 0 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Nice one!... I had a feeling that it should be just that, but couldn't come up with a clever solution like yours! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (which I didn't) I think U.index(S[i]) is what you are looking for

EDIT: so I guess you could save a dictionary of the original indices and keep the retrieval syntax pretty simple

```
OIDX = {U[i]: i for i in range(0, len(U))}
S = sorted(U)
OIDX[S[i]]
```

Comment: `index` is implemented as a linear search in Python lists.  Probably not what is being asked for.

Comment: Ah okay, you could do something like OIDX = {U[i]: i for i in range(0, len(U))} and OIDX[S[i]] for fast lookup of the original index.

Comment: Sorry the other way round - I edited the original post. Now it should be somewhat clearer.

Comment: They aren't! Meaning there are multiple Ridx's possible

Comment: @ZappaZ Ahh... I've taken a stab at an answer which I think is reasonable... Let me know if that's close...